# Calculating Immediate next future date from a list of dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets. The 1st is a list of sales reps, their accounts and some demographic information. Each row has a unique account. The 2nd is a list of actions (i.e. next steps) for each rep for each account along with a date to do them (has past and future dates).

I'm trying to import the immediate next date of action (will probably need to do VlookUp between the sheets) from the 2nd sheet into the 1st. What formula do I use? I need to fill in the yellow spaces in the 1st sheet. Thank you!

First sheet: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O58IS.png)
Second sheet: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq4Py.png)

Comment: how do you know which action is next? Is it solely based on the earliest date that hasn't passed yet?

Answer (score 0):

IF you have Office 365 Excel use MINIFS:

```
=MINIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!C:C,">" & Today(),Sheet1!B:B,B2,Sheet1!A:A,A2)
```

Remember to format the output cells as short date.

Comment: Thank you Scott! Will let you know if I face any issues with this

Answer (score 0):

Try this, entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=MIN(IF(((Sheet2!C:C>=Today())*(Sheet2!B:B=B2)*(Sheet2!A:A=A2))>0,Sheet2!C:C))
```

Comment: Thanks Fernando! Will let you know if I have any follow up questions